# What's the meaning of $\oint_{\partial\Delta}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, notation

If $f$ is a continuous function on a open set $U\subseteq \mathbb C$ and $\Delta$ is a triangle which lies in $U$, what does $$ \oint_{\partial \Delta} f(z) dz $$
exactly mean ? Path integral requires a parametrization of the boundary of $\Delta$ but it can be oriented counter-clockwise or clockwise... so how to define a piecewise smooth path $\gamma$ depending on $\Delta$ with arbitrary fixed orientation, given by a function which takes a triangle as an input and return a path at output, therefore we may denote such a path by $\partial \Delta$ to be convenient ?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: It always understood to be counterclockwise.

Comment: Ok so how can I parametrize the boundary ?

Comment: For example by gluing three affine parametrizations, one for each side.

Comment: Yes, by concatenating segment but how to choose the first vertex, the second and the last to be able to write $\gamma = [z_1z_2].[z_2z_3].[z_3,z_1]$ ?

Comment: It doesn't matter how you choose the first vertex.  You'll add up $3$ integrals, and get the same answer, so long as you observe the orientation.

Comment: There is no way to order the vertices ?

Comment: You might also want to apply Cauchy’s integral formula or even Residue theorem if more information about $f(z)$ is given!